# How do i execute a certain code?

Tags: java

So i have this code and i want it to get executed when the player types A into the console.. how am i going to do it?

```
while (Attack) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int R = r.nextInt(6 - 1) + 1;
        int R2 = r.nextInt(6 - 1) + 1;
        int R3 = r.nextInt(6 - 1) + 1;
        int R4 = r.nextInt(6 - 1) + 1;
        int R5 = r.nextInt(6 - 1) + 1;
        int R6 = r.nextInt(6 - 1) + 1;
        int totalr[] = {R, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6};
        Random x = new Random();
        int X = x.nextInt(6 - 1) + 1;
        int X2 = x.nextInt(6 - 1) + 1;
        int X3 = x.nextInt(6 - 1) + 1;
        int X4 = x.nextInt(6 - 1) + 1;
        int X5 = x.nextInt(6 - 1) + 1;
        int X6 = x.nextInt(6 - 1) + 1;
        int totalx[] = {X, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6};
```

This is the code above the code above this message xDD Confusing.. Anw so what command or what statement do i use to make that happen? Thanks for your time

```
String M2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Name2 + "'s Turn. Here are your options\n 1.Invade \n 2.Buy \n 3.End Turn \n 4.Check Money Balance \n 5.Check Soldier Count \n 6.Citizen's Hapinness \n 7.Owned Islands \n 8.Check Rules", "Type the Number of the action you want to take place");
                    if (M2.equals("1")) {
                        String Inv=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Open up the map and Check the island that you are in! If you dont remember the islands name type B to go back and then go into Owned Islands and come back! Then see the attack option you have and choose where you want to attack.Type A to Attack");
                        if(Inv.equalsIgnoreCase("A")){
                            Attack=false;
                            Attack=true;
                            continue attack;
                        }else{

                            continue P2Menu2;
                        }
                    }
```

Tip: continue does not work as well as setting the Boolean attack=true...

Comment: Please make yourself clearer, ask a specific problem.

Comment: Put it in a method and call that method when the player types A.

Comment: I think you probably need to slow down and learn the basics of variables, control structures like if statements and while or for loops, and methods before you jump into trying to make something useful.

Comment: `continue` is used to go to the next iteration in a loop. What did you think it was supposed to do?

Comment: @VivinPaliath I cant do that because some things are declared inside my main method so if i use it outside it it has errors

Comment: Then you need to pass the variables you need as arguments to the method.

Comment: @Michelle I already started and i'm pretty close at ending it so yeah..

Comment: @Michelle Now i realize how little i know about java xDD arguments? like redeclaring them ?

Comment: @Takisp22 Yes you can. Move it outside, look at the errors, and figure out how to fix them. What errors are you getting?

Comment: Then the advice @Michelle gave you is golden: learn the basics of Java programming. For example, you can pass "things" as parameters, and store back the return values of methods. Here are [the official Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you have given, I believe you are looking for the `getInputValue()` method.

In your case, you should do `String Inv = JOptionPane.getInputValue();` so that `Inv` will actually contain a valid string. Of course, I am assuming the input will always be a string and not an object.

**Edit:** would like to add that `continue` is used quite differently. A quick Google search should help you learn more.

Comment: I also completely agree with the comments. You should consider spending some time to learn the basics such as creating variables and using methods.